# Paid vacation time

Tags: management, vacation

So where I work we are allowed 5 paid vacation days a year, but I'm having trouble with trying to get my boss to understand what vacation time is. For instance, I work sunday-thursday and have Fridays and Saturdays off every week. I go and try and get a vacation day for a Sunday so that way I have a 3 days weekend, and my boss approves of it, but then wants me to 'make up' for time losses like it's a sick day. I'm just confused because if we make up paid vacation days, then wouldn't we be getting over paid?

Comment: Is it possible your boss is simply not realising that you want to take a vacation day for this? Perhaps it's common to save up overtime to take an occasional day off and save those 5 days for a "real holiday"? It could help if you mention the country you're in as well.

Comment: Why would you 'make up' for time lost due to being sick? As stated earlier stating which country this is would probably help in getting a better answer so we can put it into context, you are for instance not in Sweden since then you would have atleast 25 paid vacation days.

Comment: If you have to "make up" vacation time, then it's really not vacation time, in my opinion.  It's more like a flexible work arrangement, where instead of working Sunday, you just work more hours in the remaining 4 days.

Comment: Which country??

Comment: Have you been getting overpaid? What actually happens when you take a Sunday off? Or have you not been taking a Sunday off because your boss insists on you making up the time? Also: Do you get all five days immediately at the beginning of the year or do you earn it over time? If the latter, do you currently have enough PTO to take a whole day?

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to find a less abusive employer. 5 days a year is terrible anyway. But to then ask you to make up the time afterwards is defeating the whole point of annual leave.

Your boss is effectively asking you to take no paid time off at all.